# Using sessions to store a shopping cart using CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, session

I want to make an e-commerce website and don't want to force users have an account to purchase items, they can just do it whenever they feel like it.

Can I use the sessions class in CodeIgniter to do this, with the ability to keep a users session (i.e. their shopping cart items) for an extended period of time (maybe 6 months or a year)? I read the user guide on CI about sessions and it says it gives you the option to set sessions to not expire by stating the session_expire_on_close variable to false in the config file, which I'm guessing keeps the session running even after the user closes the browser.

Whenever a user visits the site, or adds something to their basket, I can start the session. Then when they leave and decide to come back, I can validate their shopping cart info from the sessions table in my database and give it back to them.

I also wanted to know if I should store shopping cart items in the ci_sessions table given as an example in the user guide in the user_data column? Would that be sufficient?

Just want to know if I'm heading in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: If you ask questions like that, then it may be more wise to use the CodeIgniter cart library, not saying you're lame or something, but it will be much easier to maintain. I find it is really well made and allows numerous custom fields to be present!

Comment: @Vlakarados the cart class only deals with adding/updating/deleting items in your cart, not keeping them stored for later access, right?

Comment: read this  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

Comment: @AZ1 it's obvious in the link Anooj posted, this guide or manual should be your bible or mantra or whatever, CodeIgniter is known for it's ridiculously good documentation, you should know it by heart!

Comment: @Anooj Thanks for the link, I've looked at it before but with the insight from people here I've understood what's on there :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you're on the right path.

How I'd do it (some of this may be obvious):

1. Add the `session` library to `config/autoload.php` so it starts automatically.
2. Set up the 'Session Variables' section in `config/config.php` as needed - `sess_expiration = some long time`, `sess_expire_on_close = false`, `use_database = true` etc.
3. To keep it simple, only store product IDs in the session. Below is a basic `add_to_cart` function as an example:

   ```
   public function add_to_cart($product_id) {

   // Whenever a user adds an item to their cart, pull out any they already have in there

   $cart_products = $this->session->userdata('cart_products');

   // Add the new item

   $cart_products[] = $product_id;

   // And put it back into the session

   $this->session->set_userdata('cart_products', $cart_products);

   }
   ```
4. Use the product_ids from the session to pull out more details (e.g. product name) from your db and display them on screen.

Because CI keeps its own session_id this approach should automatically repopulate the session every time the user revisits your site, you shouldn't ever need to manually query the ci_sessions table or use standard PHP sessions.

The above isn't tested but hope it helps, shout if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the help. From what people have posted in the 'general comments' section above it seems using the Cart class would be most suitable, as it uses sessions to keep track of the items in the shopping basket anyway. Looking at the documentation for the Cart class, I believe I will also need a table (ci_sessions). What do you think? I would appreciate your input :)

Comment: Indeed, the Cart class looks like it would suit you perfectly, I completely forgot it existed! Yes you'd still need a ci_sessions table, though again you shouldn't need to ever query it directly; when you convert the cart to an order just make sure you use `$this->cart->contents();` and then just process it however you want from there :-)

Comment: I'm having a real difficulty in understanding how you do not need to query the sessions table, what would be the point of it in that case? For instance, when a user adds something to their cart, they will automatically start a session (right?) and that session will last until the time for it expires or once they have destroyed the cart. The need for a sessions table is to only hold valid sessions, so that once the user is ready to purchase the order, I can validate it to make sure it is in the table? Sorry I don't understand what exactly the table will be used for

Comment: Sorry, I've just read this back and I think I confused you by trying to clarify something that you already understood! My comment above should have just said "Yes the Cart class is exactly how you described and yes you will need to use the ci_sessions table". Not sure how I completely misinterpreted your question, my apologies!

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter utilizes its own sessions ([see this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)) which do not interfere with [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Therefore you could use the regular PHP session

```
session_start();
```

that creates or reopen the existing session, which ID is stored in a cookie (usually [`PHPSESSID`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)). Then use that session instead of CodeIgniter's one

```
$_SESSION['MyData'] = 12345;
```

Maybe you could check in your CodeIgniter configuration that the cookie names do not collide in config.php, `sess_cookie_name`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't fully understand what you posted. Are you saying to use PHP sessions and check whether that session exists using PHPSESSID?

Comment: It is more simple than that. Use PHP sessions which do not interfere with CodeIgniter' ones. `PHPSESSID` is just the *cookie* name stored into your browser. You shouldn't have to worry, but if CI's cookie name is the same, there is a conflict. So I suggested you check the CI configuration to ensure `sess_cookie_name` is not 'PHPSESSID'