# after adding the product in the cart and the user refreshes the page then how can I display the data which is added in the cart

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart. I am displaying records like

**Row 1**

```
AFGFD ANAND
trdsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | duration        | price   | Action
cricket        | Select duration | 100     | Add to cart
```

**Row 2**

```
POIUY ANAND
mnbsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | duration        | price   | Action
cricket        | Select duration | 100     | Add to cart
Badminton      | Select duration | 200     | Add to cart
```

**Note**
duration is a select dropdown which is below

```
<select name="memberDuration"  class="form-control dropdownDuration"> 
<option selected disabled >Select duration</option>  
<option value="12m">1 Year</option>
<option value="6m">6 months</option>
</select>
```

Below is the final code which is working for. There is no issue with add to cart as well. The user can't add the same product more than one.

```
     foreach ($SActivity as $sec_data) {
      $counter = 0; // COUNTER FOR KNOWING POSITION IN ACTIVITIES LOOP              $num_activities = count($sec_data); // TOTAL NUMBER OF ACTIVITIES FOR THIS USER 

foreach ($sec_data as $row) { $counter++; // ADD +1 TO COUNTER FOR EACH
    ACTIVITY // ONLY PRINT OUT THE NAME AND TABLE HEADER IF FIRST ROW if($counter == 1){ ?>

    <h2>
      <?php echo $row->first_name;?>
      <?php echo $row->last_name;?>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <?php echo $row->email;?>
    </p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ActivityName</th>
          <th>duration</th>
          <th>price</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <?php } ?>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row->ActivityName;?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="memberDuration" class="form-control dropdownDuration">
              <option selected disabled>Select duration</option>
              <option value="12m">1 Year</option>
              <option value="6m">6 months</option>
            </select>

          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="calActivitylPrice"></div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="display_table">
              <?php echo $secActivity_Addtocart_active;?>
            </div>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <?php 
                // IF THIS IS THE LAST ACTIVITY OF THIS USER IN THE LOOP: PRINT TABLE END TAG
                if($counter == $num_activities){
                    echo '</tbody></table>';
                }
            } 
        }
```

example of the added product.

```
POIUY ANAND
mnbsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | duration | price   | Action
cricket        | 12m      | 100     | remove
Badminton      | 6m       | 200     | remove
```

There is no issue till now.

Now what I notice that I added a product in the cart and I refresh the page then my select dropdown and the price is not displaying.

I mean I added a product with `1 year` duration and according to the dropdown, I am displaying the price using ajax.

After adding the product in the cart and refresh the page then I am getting like

```
POIUY ANAND
mnbsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | duration        | price   | Action
cricket        | Select duration |         | remove
Badminton      | Select duration |         | remove
```

So I am trying to find the solution that after adding the product in the cart and the user refreshes the page then how can I display the data.

I found some solution and it's working. but the issue is my select dropdown is display in the all the select option and price is not displaying in the in the correct activity.

I am getting the output like. I choose 1 year from the first-row select dropdown and it displaying in the all the row

```
Row 1

AFGFD ANAND
trdsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | duration  | price   | Action
cricket        | 12m       | 100     | remove

Row 2

POIUY ANAND
mnbsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | duration  | price   | Action
cricket        | 12m       | 200     | remove
Badminton      | 12m       |         | remove



 <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->ActivityName;?>
      </td>
      <td>
    <?php 
     $product['options']['duration']=0;
    if (in_array($activityNO, array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id'))){
            foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product) { 
               //break;
             } }?>
                  <select name="memberDuration"  class="form-control dropdownDuration"> 
        <option selected disabled >Select duration</option>  
                <option value="12m" <?php if($product['options']['duration'] == "12m"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >1 Year</option>
                <option value="6m" <?php if($product['options']['duration'] == "6m"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>6 months</option>
              </select>


      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="calActivitylPrice">

            <?php if (in_array($activityNO, array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id'))){
            foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product)  {
              if ($product['id'] == $activityNO) { 
                //print_r($product['price']);
                $priceAct = $product['price']; 
              }
              //
            }
                print_r($priceAct);
          }
      ?>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="display_table">
          <?php echo $Addtocart_active;?>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Value of $this->cart->contents()

```
 Array
    (
        [dc54c1ce61893fa725cf87c9e20b4c78] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => cricket
                [qty] => 1
                [price] => 100
                [options] => Array
                    (
                        [duration => 12m
                    )

                [rowid] => dc54c1ce61893fa725cf87c9e20b4c78
            )

        [e5966e762beda1762e461f27f1dc3ef4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Badminton 
                [qty] => 1
                [price] => 200
                [options] => Array
                    (
                        [duration] => 6m
                    )

                [rowid] => e5966e762beda1762e461f27f1dc3ef4
            )

    )
```

Comment: as i have seen your other questions, one big mistake you are doing is you are not using sessions for a shopping cart site.
you always need session, i assume you know what they are

Comment: @HabibRehman, do you have any link or videos or any example where I can check it? It will be a great help for me.

Comment: checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XF7Bui6jUFc this tut is little old but i think iit will be pretty fine

Comment: if you see at time 0:25 he refreshes, that's where he's using session and everything is fine, also found the text explanation with source code
https://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/ajax-jquery-codeigniter-shopping-cart.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706484/using-sessions-to-store-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter check this out too

Comment: @HabibRehman, Thanks for the link. I will check it and update you.

Answer (score 0):

*Update according to update*

In this block

```
            foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product) {
```

You check $activityNO in the added carts and it is possibly true, but in foreach loop, you didn't get the correct $activityNO value from cart content.

And by the way, your solution is not good, you are using many foreach.

To optimize it, only loop one time and prepare your date and then render.

```
<?php
$productsInCart = [];
// Loop and prepare data similar to below
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $cart) {
    $productsInCart[$cart['id']] = $cart;
}
?>

<?php 
foreach ($sec_data as $row) {
    $activityNo = $row->activityNo; // I am not sure about this
?>

<h2>
  <?php echo $row->first_name;?>
  <?php echo $row->last_name;?>
</h2>

<select name="memberDuration" class="form-control dropdownDuration"> 
    <option <?php if (empty($productsInCart[$activityNo])) { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> disabled >Select duration</option>  
    <option value="12m" <?php if($productsInCart[$activityNo]['options']['duration'] == "12m"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >1 Year</option>
    <option value="6m" <?php if($productsInCart[$activityNo]['options']['duration'] == "6m"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>6 months</option>
</select>

<?php
} // END foreach
?>
```

And apply the same strategy for below price.

Note: Above code is only the idea, it is not working 100%.

---

To do that, you need to user one of suggestion solutions below, depends on you requirement.

1. Using Session to store cart info

   - Store cart to user Session when user add to cart
   - Load cart from Session if you want to read it (From the page you want to show)
   - Using this way, cart data is only available on Session scope
2. Using database to store cart info

   - Store cart to your Database when user add to cart
   - Load cart from Database if you want to read it (From the page you want to show)
   - More complicated solution, but is is perpetual cart and can share among different browser for one user.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart. Cart information is stored in the $this->cart->contents(). It's working perfectly but when I refresh then I not getting the data.

Comment: I also found some solution but getting some issue. I updated on the question.

Comment: Please give me value of `$this->cart->contents()` and please remove selected in "<option selected disabled >Select duration</option>" in case user have selected value

Comment: I updated the value of $this->cart->contents() in the question. Everything is working but the issue is If I refresh the page then getting some issue. I updated the solution but not working 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, give me some time to check out your answer.

Comment: You have to loop though $this->cart->contents() and add product id as key. and then product cart content as value

Comment: I am a little bit confused. I am still struggling where should I declare then foreach conditions and how?

Comment: give me some time to check.